# How can python return the filename currently being processed under Windows

Tags: python, mako

I am new to python, and just want to make a simple change.  We are generating a template file via mako under Windows 7 and I want to change the comments at the start of the output file from:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This file is automatically generated by Mako
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

to

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This file is automatically generated by Mako from ${filename}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

so, what is the real code to insert the actual filename being processed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import os

filename = os.path.basename(__file__)
print ('this is generated by ' + filename)
```

Comment: Edited the answer. This will give you the filename only, not the filepath also.

Answer (score 1):

For the name of the python script itself, use `__file__`:

```
$ echo "print __file__" > test.py                    
$ python test.py 
test.py
```